# Use MS SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, reporting

While writing this question I had a simple idea which fixed the issue. Maybe other people have the same problem or you would like to comment this so I'm posting it anyways.

tldr/simplified question:
How do i use MS SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services in Visual Studio 2010?

Solution:
Just copy the Visual Studio 2008 Reporting DLLs in your project and include them as references. I guess you have to own a licence for vss2008 when doing this but technically this solves the issue.

Original question:

> How can i use MS SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services in Visual Studio
>   2010? The reason i ask this is the following: We migrated to
>   VSS 2010 as our IDE but are still using MS SQL Server 2005.
>
> Now, i want to change a piece of code in a Project which makes use of
>   Reporting Services on said SQL Server.
>
> After converting the Solution to a VSS2010 Solution I get BuildErrors
>   because it can't find the namespaces "ReportViewer" and "Reporting".
>   That's because the references to
>
> - Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common (9.0.0.0)
> - Micrsofot.ReportViewer.WinForms (9.0.0.0)
>
> Are no longer resolvable. So i have to replace them with the
>   references to the same Assemblies in Version 10.0.0.0.
>
> After doing that the Solution builds successfully, but when opening
>   the ReportViewer i get an SoapVersionMismatchException telling me that
>   for Remote-Processing i have to use Microsoft SQL Server 2008
>   Reporting Services or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the old references to your project. You can find them on your 2005 reporting server.

These can be found on your reporting server in the GAC.